# Active tab is not highlighted on both parent and meta

Tags: bug, status-completed, user-interface

On `IE8` active tab (such as `Questions`, `Tags`, `Users` etc) is not highlighted. So you can't tell where you are unless you read the URL or the text below the tabs (which I always find myself too lazy to do, and which is strange anyway compared to all other SE sites).

Comment: Confirmed on Chrome 7 and Safari 5 as well. Now that I think about it, does *any* browser do this with the current design?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fix is on prod now. please verify.

Comment: Seems to work!``

Comment: Yeah, it's working.