# Ask Question background color glitch

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

I noticed on the Ask Question page, the link graphic has a white background that wasn't there before. I believe this is a new bug introduced from fixing the [Active Tab highlight](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1345/active-tab-is-not-highlighted-on-both-parent-and-meta) problem.

[image]

I demand a fix now!

Answer (score 2):

calm down, fix will be in the next deployment.

Comment: I think I'm seeing double. WHAT IS GOING ON IN THIS QUESTION?! OP ARGUES WITH OP, NEWS AT 11.

Comment: @VxJasonxV I'mma flag you as being insensitive to [DID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dissociative_identity_disorder). Except not really.